# Postfix header ... change hostname?

Tags: postfix, hostname

Here's an header from a testing email sent to gmail from my mail server.  I changed Hostname from ads.jeuxgratuits.net to mail.jeuxgratuits.net so that my email header show consistent information... but even after the change I stil got a reference to ads.jeuxgratuits.net:

```
Received: from mail.jeuxgratuits.net (ads.jeuxgratuits.net [208.111.94.17])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTP id 12si2715274iwn.15.2009.10.15.13.40.35;
```

I used webmin to change the server hostname.  Then I restarted network and postfix services.

Full header:

```
Delivered-To: plehoux@gmail.com
Received: by 10.86.27.7 with SMTP id a7cs114739fga;
        Thu, 15 Oct 2009 13:40:37 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.101.180.33 with SMTP id h33mr782170anp.155.1255639236254;
        Thu, 15 Oct 2009 13:40:36 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <activation@jeuxgratuits.net>
Received: from mail.jeuxgratuits.net (ads.jeuxgratuits.net [208.111.94.17])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id 12si2715274iwn.15.2009.10.15.13.40.35;
        Thu, 15 Oct 2009 13:40:36 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of activation@jeuxgratuits.net designates 208.111.94.17 as permitted sender) client-ip=208.111.94.17;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of activation@jeuxgratuits.net designates 208.111.94.17 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=activation@jeuxgratuits.net
Received: from web03.jeuxgratuits.net (unknown [208.111.94.13])
    by mail.jeuxgratuits.net (Postfix) with ESMTP id 508D321F802E
    for <plehoux@gmail.com>; Thu, 15 Oct 2009 16:25:29 -0400 (EDT)
Date: Thu, 15 Oct 2009 16:51:29 -0400
To: plehoux@gmail.com
From: Root User <activation@jeuxgratuits.net>
Subject: =?ISO-8859-1?Q?Activation www.jeuxgratuits.net?=
Message-ID: <1797fb878a38cda837c06c43f32485b2@web03.jeuxgratuits.net>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.0.0 (phpmailer.codeworxtech.com)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your DNS is bad : 208.111.94.17
17.94.111.208.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer ads.jeuxgratuits.net.

So you need to change your DNS and wait for propagation

Answer (score 1):

Please state your answer in the form of a question... :)

The Received: line is picking up the old name from a reverse DNS lookup.